# Non-isomorphic grid graphs example

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I am looking for examples of two non-[isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) grid graphs in which every vertex have same degree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider planar hexagonal lattice and cubic 3D lattice. Every vertex in both has degree 6, yet the former lattice has cycles of length 3, while the latter doesn't, hence they aren't isomorphic.